# Check if file exists in shared network drive

Tags: python, macos, mount

I'm trying to determine if a directory exists on a shared network drive.

```
import os

if(os.path.exists('/Volumes')):
 print 'path exists'
else:
 print 'path does not exist'
```

This works fine but this fails when passing in this argument: '/Volumes/A21\ 's\ Public\ Folder'

This makes sense to me because this does not exist until I open up the shared drive on Finder. So I guess I need to mount first, which I've tried from the command line first -

```
mount_smbfs smb://guest@server/A21's Public Folder
```

This fails, so I'm unsure of what to pass in for the os.path.exists argument. Ideally, I want to be able to mount into /Volumes/A21's Public Folder first, and then later check if that folder exists?

Comment: What exactly are you mounting it to? It appears you're not mounting it at all... you need a mount point.

Comment: That's correct, I was not mounting earlier. So I have added this line before the if statement - os.system("osascript -e 'mount volume \"smb://A21._smb._tcp.local/A21\'s\ Public\ Folder\"'") but it's failing due to incorrect quote markup. I presume this would enable the folder to be accessed under /Volumes?

Comment: You can put it under `/Volumes`, although I prefer the users home directory because you know it has the proper permissions; you could always make a symlink from `/Volumes` to `~/mnt` also I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your copying and pasting the string.  I've had problems with this before.  When dealing with file paths it's best to use os join you encounter less problems

Try using:

```
os.path.join
```

for example:

```
import os

pathtodrive = os.path.join("Volumes", "A21's Public Folder")

if (os.path.exists(pathtodrive)):
    print 'path exists'
else:
    print 'path does not exist'
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I think problem is that it doesn't even recognize the network drive without being mounted.

Comment: Have you tried using exceptions to see what error it produces?

Answer (score 0):

In `Python` you would do basically the same routine as you would in `Bash` mounting shares:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

home = os.path.expanduser("~")
mnt = home + "/mnt"

if not os.path.exists(mnt): os.makedirs(mnt)
os.chdir(mnt)

os.system("mount_smbfs //username@server._smb._tcp.local/share " + mnt)
```

What this does is sets the mount point to `mnt` in the users home directory; if the folder doesn't exist then it creates it. Then the command changes into that directory and mounts the`smb`. You'll need to enter your password, or if you want to have a really non-secure way, then you can always include the password in the command (eg. `username:password`).

Once your share is mounted you can check if the file exists with:

```
os.path.exists(mnt + "/path/to/file")
```

Comment: I receive a mount error saying no such file or directory: /Users/username/mnt. I'm able to normally connect as a guest at least via finder. Do I need to still specify a username?

Comment: @A21: Yes "username" is the name of your user, so replace any instances of that with your account.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't connect to that server other than as a guest.

Comment: @A21: Then replace `username` with `guest`, and it should still work the same way.

Comment: I still receive a mount error: /Users/username/mnt: No such file or directory. I was able to get this in /Volumes by using os.system("osascript -e 'mount volume \"smb://guest@server._smb._tcp.local\"'") though.

Comment: Show me the **exact** command you are using for the mount. It should **not** be `/Users/username/mnt`, it should be `/Users/<the name of your account>/mnt`. And if you used the code exactly as I show above there should not be any issue, as the `mnt` directory is created if it doesn't exist. If the error is coming back literally "/Users/username/mnt" doesn't exist that's the entire problem. So you are either leaving something out, or there's some other issue going on within your environment. Run the code above **without** the last line included (os.system ...) - and reply back with the result.

Comment: Yes "username" is not literally username but rather my account name (A21). It creates a directory /mnt  in /Users/<username>/mnt, however when I include the os.system line, the previous error message I mentioned is what I'm receiving. The issue is that I am not a registered user on the shared network with a password, however I can get to it via guest.This may be the cause for the environment issue?

Comment: The previous command I referenced came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598313/mounting-smb-network-share-on-desktop?rq=1.

Comment: In Terminal: `mount_smbfs //guest@server._smb._tcp.local/ ~/mnt` — what is the result? Maybe try it without `~/mnt` as well. If the `"osascript -e 'mount volume \"smb://guest@server._smb._tcp.local\"'"` method works then I don't see why that shouldn't work from within Python as well...